# How can I obtain a newer GCC? I don't have root, and can't compile it (memory error)

Tags: linux, gcc, build

I have a shared account on a machine that is running an older version of GCC. I do not have root. When I try to compile GCC, my build process gets killed due to memory usage from the following command:

```
build/genattrtab ../../../work/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/common.md ../../../work/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/config/i386/i386.md insn-conditions.md \
    -Atmp-attrtab.c -Dtmp-dfatab.c -Ltmp-latencytab.c
```

I'd really like to be able to compile some software on this machine that requires a newer GCC. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually unpack one of the GCC packages for any major distribution, try to use the package that closely matches your distribution.  These installable packages are just tar files with some meta data and install script.  You can unpack them and extract binaries that you'll need.  Just keep in mind that you might need to more than just gcc package.  Some distributions chop their devtools into tons of small packages ( gcc,  g++, binutils, gdb)

Another good source is to use pre-build gcc toolchain used by embedded vendors, sometimes these vendors include host version of gcc together with cross-compiler.  For example Android NDK is one of such distributions.

Finally, you can compile GCC on another machine that is not so restrictive and copy the resulting binaries to your restrictive machine.  As in case of the first approach of unpacking installable package, try to find machine that resembles your restrictive machine as close as possible.  You can use tools like vagrant and docker to set-up close replica of your target machine.  Vagrant and docker have a lot of pre-built templates that you can use as a jump start to create the machine you need.

Comment: I made several attempts at using official packages and haven't been able to get anywhere due to dependencies and linker paths. :( The machine is on Ubuntu 12.04 and there aren't backports of the versions I need. I'll have to look into the other options.

Comment: ? Which OS have you got ? These two commands will show : 1) `uname -m` 2) `cat  etc/issue` .... And : You probably do not need the latest gcc = 6.x . A gcc-4.8.x or 4.9.x may do a better job. ... ? Which version is your current gcc ?

Comment: x86_64, Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS. I did try downloading 4.8 debs, but I think I got lost as to how to make them work with all the environment variables and dependencies when it came to compiling.

Comment: Which deb did you download.  There is no official deb for 4.8 for 12.04 it stops at 4.7  http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&keywords=gcc-4.7  however there is a backport PPA of 4.9  https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test/+build/6536420 here

Comment: The problem, I think, is when it comes to actually using the packages. The newer GCC has libatomic, but the build script I'm trying to run complained that it could not find that (ld error). I was using dpkg -x to extract things into ~/root. It seems like there's a particular set of prerequisites, paths, and environment variables I need to have ready - but I can't find a checklist for doing such a thing. So, to your original point, I might have better luck with setting up a VM on Ubuntu 12.04 and compiling there.